# How Do I Optimize This SQL Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I have one of my billing alerts query is timing out in Exact Target, Automation Studio. Exact Target support has recommend to Optimize the Query.

Here is the Query;

```
SELECT c.PolicyNumber+c.Email+c.FirstName+c.LastName+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),c.DOB,10) as UniqueContactKey,
c.Email,
c.LastName,
c.DOB,
c.PolicyNumber,
c.FirstName,
c.AgencyName,
c.AgencyPhone,
c.Company,
c.Corporation,
c.Last4DigitsPolicyNumber,
c.OriginalEffectiveDate,
c.PolicyEffectiveDate,
c.PolicyExpirationDate,
c.PolicyType,
c.PrimaryCity,
c.Age,
b.EFTAmount,
b.EFTDate,
b.InvoiceAmount,
b.InvoiceDate,
b.MinimumDueAmount,
b.NotProcessedAmount,
b.PaymentDueDate,
b.PaymentReceivedAmount,
b.PaymentReceivedDate,
q.can_contact,
c.RecordType,
c.OriginalDOB,
b.AlertName,
b.InsertedDate
FROM
Contacts c 
INNER JOIN Billing_Alerts b on b.PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber
LEFT JOIN [Quote - Calculated] q on q.PolicyNumber = c.PolicyNumber
```

In Contact table I have 1,096,300 of records
Billing_Alert: 4,497,023 records
Quote - Calculated: 479,943

Any solution please?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to have a separate query for each Data Extension you're adjoining.  The first would *overwrite* and the next two would *update*.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT 
c.PolicyNumber+c.Email+c.FirstName+c.LastName+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),c.DOB,10) as UniqueContactKey,
c.Email,
c.LastName,
c.DOB,
c.PolicyNumber,
c.FirstName,
c.AgencyName,
c.AgencyPhone,
c.Company,
c.Corporation,
c.Last4DigitsPolicyNumber,
c.OriginalEffectiveDate,
c.PolicyEffectiveDate,
c.PolicyExpirationDate,
c.PolicyType,
c.PrimaryCity,
c.Age
from Contact C
/* target: NewDE */ 
/* action: overwrite */
```

**Query #2**

```
select 
/* whatever fields here */
from NewDE n
INNER JOIN Billing_Alerts b on b.PolicyNumber = n.PolicyNumber
/* target: NewDE */
/* action: update */
```

**Query #3**

```
select 
/* whatever fields here */
from NewDE n
LEFT JOIN [Quote - Calculated] q on q.PolicyNumber = n.PolicyNumber
/* target: NewDE */
/* action: update */
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add Subquery on Join? For example the Billing_Alerts table updates daily with field name insert date. So from optimization perspective i was thinking why not I create a subquery where I will first fetch rows where insertdate is equal to today? So In this case I can keep the one single query, rather than three.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Unless your like dealing with timeouts in the platform, then my recommendation would be to break it out into multiple queries.